# SharePoint 2010 - RichImageField not displaying in display mode

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, publishing, page-layout

I am currently doing some research into SharePoint Page Layouts and building pages based on those layouts.

I currently have a page layout containing several RichImageFields and RichHtmlFields, but it seems that the first RichImageField is not displaying (doesn't even render out anything).
As far as I can see, he's the same as the others:

```
    <div id="headerImage">
        <PublishingWebControls:RichImageField id="HeaderImage" FieldName="HeaderImage1" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div id="middleContent">
        <div id="left">
            <div id="about">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>About</legend>
                    <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField ID="About" FieldName="AboutMedicInfo1" runat="server"/>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div id="items">
                <h1>
                <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="ItemsTitle1" runat="server"/></h1>
                <PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" CssClass="edit-mode-panel">
                    <SharePointWebControls:TextField runat="server" FieldName="ItemsTitle1" />
                </PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
                <div id="Item1">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>
                        <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Item11" runat="server"/></legend>
                        <PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" CssClass="edit-mode-panel">
                            <SharePointWebControls:TextField runat="server" FieldName="Item11" />
                        </PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
                        <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField ID="Item1" FieldName="Item1Content1" runat="server"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div id="Item2">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>
                        <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Item21" runat="server"/></legend>
                        <PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" CssClass="edit-mode-panel">
                            <SharePointWebControls:TextField runat="server" FieldName="Item21" />
                        </PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
                        <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField ID="Item2" FieldName="Item2Content1" runat="server"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="center">
            <div>
                <PublishingWebControls:RichImageField id="HighLight1" FieldName="HighLight11" runat="server"/></div>
            <div>
                <PublishingWebControls:RichImageField id="HighLight2" FieldName="HighLight22" runat="server"/></div>
            <div>
                <PublishingWebControls:RichImageField id="HighLight3" FieldName="HighLight32" runat="server"/></div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div id="report">
                <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField ID="Report" FieldName="Report" runat="server"/>
            </div>
            <div id="webparts">
                <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Rechtsonder" ID="BottomRightControl"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The funny thing is that I'm perfectly able to see the image when I'm in editing mode and when I'm viewing the Page Library items (after I added the specified field to the view).

Does anyone have any experience with this? Feel free to ask further questions if I might be unclear.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I should have checked before posting my initial question. It turned out that my problem was because I was using the Page content type, instead of the Article Page or Welcome Page content types. The Page CT doesn't have the field that the image was looking for.

What I find really interesting is that it still let me select the image AND it stored the value somewhere... even though there was no official field for it. I suspect that the field in the library is there, since you would need it for your other content types.

Anyway, hoping that someone else may find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't miss the two properties `RichText="TRUE"` and `RichTextMode="FullHtml"` of the image field definition to be like:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
  <Field
     ID="{4ea31e74-f59d-4ddf-863c-607a01735f65}"
     Name="pls_H2_2_Image"
     DisplayName="Titel 2 Bild"
     Type="Image"
     Required="FALSE"
     RichText="TRUE"
     RichTextMode="FullHtml"
     Group="Custom">
  </Field>
</Elements>
```

I faced this issue before and this solution did it properly.